# System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0 exeption

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0

In my console C# app I have this lines:

```
ServerManager sm = new ServerManager();
SiteCollection sc = sm.Sites;
```

I added reference to  `Microsoft.Web.Administration` as needed. but I get the exeption:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the latest `System.Runtime` nuget package from nuget?

Comment: `Microsoft.Web.Administration` is a NuGet package. It should have added any required dependencies itself. How did you add `Microsoft.Web.Administration` ? What .NET Runtime version do you target?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My app targets `4.6.2`, I added `Microsoft.Web.Administration` manually, I mean I downloaded only this dll and added reference to it.

Comment: @CPU don't *download*. Add the NuGet package which will bring in the correct dependencies. Although I'd suggest targeting 4.7.2. That's the only runtime version that's truly .NET Standard 2.0 compliant. In all previous versions adding a .NET Standard package like `Microsoft.Web.Administration` will bring in a ton of dependencies and add binding redirects to your app.config

Comment: @CPU for example, the latest `Microsoft.Web.Administration` depends on the [NETStandard.Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/) package. For any version below 4.7.2 (that's under .NETStandard 2.0) you'll see it adds a ton of compatiblity packages. Each of them will add its own redirects to app.config. Any mixup in version can end up with a 4.1 redirect when 4.3 is installed

Comment: @CPU *sometimes* you can fix the problem by *removing* all redirects. Sometimes you'll have to remove all packages and reinstall them.  It's better to target 4.7.2 and have as few of them as possible though. Start with a *clean* console application targeting the highest Runtime version you can and add [Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Administration/). Does your application run?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will try that and would let you know

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This Nuget package contains ~100 dlls, do you think I should add them all?

Comment: @CPU you shouldn't add *any* of them. They are added automatically when you add the package to your project. How *did* you add `Microsoft.Web.Administration`? Did you go to `Manage NuGet Packages` (the correct way) or `Add References` (wrong) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to  modify the app.config entry to match packages.config for the newVersion as below.

You have to check with the packages.config to know the exact version

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b0123f7facd50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.6.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```